# If $A \in M_5(\mathbb R)$ and $A^2-4A-I=0$ find $(a_1-\frac{1}{a_1})+\ldots+(a_5-\frac{1}{a_5})$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A \in M_5(\mathbb R)$ and $A^2-4A-I=0$,  moreover we consider $a_1$, $a_2$, $\ldots$ $a_5$ be eigen value of $A$, I gonna find  $(a_1-\frac{1}{a_1})+\ldots+(a_5-\frac{1}{a_5})$, while I have no idea how to proceed, any piece of advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $A$ is invertible, we may write
$$
A -4I -A^{-1} = 0
$$
Now take the trace on both sides. We get
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A) - 4\operatorname{tr}(I) - \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}) = 0
$$
Now, we know two things:

- The trace of a matrix is the sum of its eigenvalues
- The eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of $A$

Also, since these matrices are $5\times 5$, we have $\operatorname{tr}(I) = 5$.

This gives
$$
a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+a_5 - 4\cdot 5 - \frac1{a_1}- \frac1{a_2}- \frac1{a_3}- \frac1{a_4}- \frac1{a_5} = 0
$$
from which you can easily extract the answer you're looking for.

Comment: You can find there :https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2200369/a-question-about-eigenvalues-of-5-times5-matrix

Comment: Since $A(A-4I)=I$, $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @See-WooLee You're right, the given relation itself implies that $A$ is invertible.